# Error displaying articles from Cloud firestore in React

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm taking the React course at coderhouse and we're taking Firebase's Firestore database; We are setting up a virtual store and we have to bring the articles from the database, I have the following problem when I want to bring the articles of a category it brings it to me but when I want them to load everything, what would it be in the index the page does not load.

Can you tell me why? Thank you. I leave you my code and the error it is giving me, how do I solve it, thank you.

```
React-dom.development.js:22738 Uncaught FirebaseError: Function where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined
```

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import '../App.css';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css';  
import ItemList from './ItemList';
import CircularProgress from '@mui/material/CircularProgress';
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { db } from '../firebase/firebase';
import { getDocs, collection, query, where, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";


export const ItemListContainer =() =>  {

  const [swSell,setSwSell] = useState([])
  const [cargar,setCargar] = useState(true)

  const {categoryID} = useParams();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const productCollection = collection(db, 'Products');
    const productQuery = query(productCollection, where('category', '==', categoryID));
    const URL= categoryID  == null ? productQuery : productCollection;
    console.log(URL)
    getDocs(URL)
     .then(result => {
        const lista  = result.docs.map(element => {
          return {
            ...element.data(),
          }
        })
      setSwSell(lista);
     })
     .catch(error => console.err)
     .finally(() => setCargar(false));
    
    /* const URL = categoryID 

  return(
    <>
      {
        <main className="items">
          <div className="parent" key={swSell.id}>
            {cargar ? <CircularProgress color="primary"/>:<ItemList product={swSell} />}
          </div>
        </main>
      }
    </>
    );
  }
export default ItemListContainer;
```

Comment: `categoryID` is undefined. Check that parameter

Comment: IF I obtain that variable by url since it is obtained through a userparams

Comment: The error `Uncaught FirebaseError: Function where() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined` is clearly saying that you are passing an undefined value. Check that `categoryID` has a value

Comment: Let's see, he explained, the categoryID variable can be empty or it can be, for example, electronics or men's clothing, when doing getDocs it only prints when category is not empty.
The question is how to fix it

Thank you

Comment: First of all, how is he? Who explain that to you? Second of all, please just console log `categoryID` to see its value

Comment: first, Yes i see CategoryID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should run the query when categoryID is not null. Hence your ternary operator should be opposite.

```
const URL = categoryID  === null ? productCollection : productQuery;
```